# Magento 2: How to get product id from order invoice?

Tags: magento2, invoice, create-invoice

i am trying to overwrite invoice tax model, and I want to get the product id. for the invoice item. But it returns the parent product id if purchased product is a configurable product.

file `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Total\Tax.php`

**Code**

```
foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {

             $orderItem = $item->getOrderItem();
            var_dump($item->getProductId());
            die('from invoice model...');
```

It returns parent product id but I want the purchased product id, how can I do it.

Please help.

Comment: please try $invoice->getAllVisibleItems()

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA It result in error.

Answer (score 0):

You can based on this plugin :

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Order/Admin/Item/Plugin/Configurable.php:79

/**
 * Get product id
 *
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Admin\Item $subject
 * @param callable $proceed
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $item
 *
 * @return int
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function aroundGetProductId(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Admin\Item $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $item
) {
    if ($item->getProductType() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $productOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        return $product->getIdBySku($productOptions['simple_sku']);
    }
    return $proceed($item);
}
```